# non-conical support of fundamental solution possible?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, fourier-analysis

In his [1970 paper](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1970.1/Main/icm1970.1.0121.0134.ocr.pdf), on page 124, Hormander discusses fundamental solutions of linear PDE with constant coefficients. I notice he only discusses cases where the support $F$ of the fundamental solution is either a half-space or contained in a proper cone. Are there known constant-coefficient PDE's whose fundamental solution has a support $F$ which is not contained in a proper cone nor does it fill up a half-space (Say, there exists a plane $H$ where for every point $x \in H_0$ there is an open ball $B_x$ centered on $x$ so that $F\cap B_x = \emptyset$).

I'm not an expert in the subject, so I apologize beforehand if the question is too standard.